# What's the reason behind having std::integral_constant?

Tags: c++, std

What's the real use case of this?

```
std::integral_constant
```

I can understand this is a wrapper with value 2:

```
typedef std::integral_constant<int, 2> two_t
```

But why not just use 2 or define a const int value with 2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few cases where `std::integral_constant` is very useful.

One of them is tag dispatch. For example, `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` are simply `std::integral_constant<bool, true>` and `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` respectively. Every [type trait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) derives from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`, which enables tag dispatch:

```
template <typename T>
int foo_impl(T value, std::true_type) {
    // Implementation for arithmetic values
}

template <typename T>
double foo_impl(T value, std::false_type) {
    // Implementation for non-arithmetic values
}

template <typename T>
auto foo(T value) {
    // Calls the correct implementation function, which return different types.
    // foo's return type is `int` if it calls the `std::true_type` overload
    // and `double` if it calls the `std::false_type` overload
    return foo_impl(value, std::is_arithmetic<T>{});
}
```

---

Also, template metaprogramming libraries typically only have algorithms on lists of types rather than lists of values. If you wanted to use those algorithms for values instead, you'd have to use something like `std::integral_constant`

Comment: Is it equivalent  as adding an if-else check, besides the performance gain of generating the code at compiling time?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld No. You could even do things like returning different types in the different implementations. That wouldn't compile with just an `if`. However, in C++17, we get `if constexpr`, which does work for this use case.

Comment: What if instead of std::true_type you took a bool and in instead of passing in std::is_arithmetic<T>{} you passed in std::is_arithmetic::value?

Comment: @Zebrafish Then you'd always get a `bool` regardless of whether the trait is true or not, which means that you'd only be able to have the one overload. That doesn't allow for things such as different return types or implementations which only compile if true vs. false.

Answer (score 8):

`2` is value, while `two_t` is a type. They are two different abstractions. Each has its purpose.

- You can't use `2` where a type is expected.
- You can't use `two_t`  where an integral value is expected.

More importantly, `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` are the most widely used specializations of `std::integral_constant`. They are extensively used in [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

Comment: Given that we can have non-type template parameters, what are the cases where we can use a type but not an integral value?  If we had traits classes with members that are constant integral expressions, instead of members that are `true_type` or `false_type`, what would that preclude?

Comment: @Maxpm, I am a little confused by your question. Whether you can use a type or a value to instantiate a template depends on how a template is defined. I don't follow your train of thought regarding the second question.

Comment: It depends on how the template is defined, yes, but for metaprogramming purposes, we can define templates however we want.  Why invent a type-based way of representing integral constants when we have a perfectly good value-based way already built in to the language?  For my second question: as you said, `true_type` and `false_type` are extensively used in type traits - but how is that an improvement over [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daf8c8d81560b6b5)?

Comment: @Maxpm, thanks for clarifying your questions. The answers to those questions are not only long but philosophical too. This is not the right place to answer them.

Comment: Okay. “This is not the right place to answer them” meaning this comment thread, or this question, or Stack Overflow in general?

Comment: @Maxpm, not in the comment thread, not in this question. It might be possible in SO if the question is framed properly. if you ask a question of that kind, you risk it being closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 5):

Below code snippet is one way I used std::integral_constant to create an api which takes a generic value but it also checks at compile time that the value you are providing is valid or not.

```
#include<iostream>

struct Value {};
struct Color {};
struct Size {};
struct Point {};

enum class Property {
    Color,
    StrokeColor,
    Opacity,
    Size,
    Position,
};

class Dom {
public:
    // give a single api to setValue
    template<Property prop, typename AnyValue>
    void setValue(const std::string &obj, AnyValue value){
        setValue(std::integral_constant<Property, prop>{}, obj, value);
    }
private:
    // specialization for each property and value type pair.
    void setValue(std::integral_constant<Property, Property::Color> type,
                  const std::string &obj,
                  Color col) {std::cout<<" update color property\n";}
    void setValue(std::integral_constant<Property, Property::StrokeColor> type,
                  const std::string &obj,
                  Color col){std::cout<<" update stroke color property\n";}
    void setValue(std::integral_constant<Property, Property::Opacity> type,
                  const std::string &obj,
                  Value opacity){std::cout<<" update opacity property\n";}
};

int main()
{
    Dom domObj;
    // try to update the color property of rect1 object inside layer1
    domObj.setValue<Property::Color>("layer1.rect1", Color());

    // compile time error expects Color value but given Size value
    //domObj.setValue<Property::Color>("layer1.rect1", Size());
    return 0;
}
```